# UrlProperty and relative URLs

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, user-controls, hyperlink

I have a custom UserControl (inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl) with this property, which should be set to a URL on the site that you want to link to:

```
 [DefaultValue("~/NewsItem.aspx"), UrlProperty("*.aspx")]
 public string InternalItemViewUrl
 {
  get { return _internalItemViewUrl; }
  set { _internalItemViewUrl = value; }
 }
```

The control will present the URL picker drop-down correctly, but if you select a URL from the list, it does not change it to a site-relative "~/foo.aspx" link, like HyperLink does, but instead only gets "foo.aspx" which does not work (the control is in /controls and the page obviously is not). If you scroll all the way down and use "Pick URL..." which opens the full pop-up window, a page selected in that dialog does get converted to "~/foo.aspx"

Am I missing something obvious here to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the attributes on the HyperLink, especially the `[Editor]` attribute.

```
[DefaultValue(""),
 WebSysDescription("HyperLink_NavigateUrl"),
 UrlProperty, Bindable(true), WebCategory("Navigation"), 
 Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

Comment: WebCategory and WebSysDescription are internal to System.Web. My first thought was to reflector System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink.NavigateUrl too. 
 
I can set it as such, but it still behaves the same way, no ~.

<code>
 [DefaultValue(""),
  UrlProperty, Bindable(true),
  Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
</code>

Comment: Hmmm. I thought for certain the Editor attribute would square things away for you. As an aside, you can swap `WebSysDescription` for `Description` and `WebCategory` for `Category`, but those attributes aren't the source or solution of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. If I select the item directly from the intellisense drop-down, no tilde. If I scroll down to "Pick Url..." and use that dialog, it works normally. For now I'm just removing the UrlProperty attribute, because I figure you're more likely to type the ~ if you have to do it manually than if you get intellisense, pick a file, and it doesn't get corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the control is, the url is relative the page the control is placed on.
So if the control is placed on page "foo.aspx" and it references a page "foo2.aspx" (that is in the same directory as "foo.aspx"), then just haveing "foo2.aspx" in the control's url property will work.

Comment: This question is 3 years old; I can't remember the context any more. My guess is that I worked around the problem by use Page.ResolveUrl in a lifecycle event. The URLs must have been being generated relative to the control for some reason, instead of the page they were on.